# Netbeans EXE not working when executed from Terminal - CentOs

Tags: c, linux, netbeans, centos, sasl

I made Netbeans work environment with SASL. The sample codes get build and it also run properly from Netbeans. But when I try to run my exe from Terminal it is not working. The error says as below:

> ./cppapplication_1: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libanonymous.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I tried setting the PATH using the below Command :

> export PATH=/usr/lib64/sasl2/:$PATH

Still I am getting the same error. Do I need anything extra to do?

Comment: Can you try with /usr/lib/sasl2

Comment: @Anon my .so files are in /usr/lib64 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the path to `libanonymous` to the enviroment variable `LD_LOAD_LIBRARY`.

**Update:**

To do so:

1. Locate the library, for example doing: `find / -name "libanonymous.so.2"` or by `locate libanonymous.so.2`
2. Add the path found like so: `export LD_LOAD_LIBRARY=$LD_LOAD_LIBRARY:<path to lib>`

**Update 1:**

From your comment to *Anon*'s answer I see that the lib in question is located under `/usr/lib64/sasl2/`.

So you might like to set `LD_LOAD_LIBRAY` path like so:

```
export LD_LOAD_LIBRARY=$LD_LOAD_LIBRARY:/usr/lib64/sasl2/
```

**Update 2**

This needs to be done in the same shell that later then executes the program needing the libraries (`cppapplication_1`).

```
cd <dir for cppapplication_1>; export LD_LOAD_LIBRARY=$LD_LOAD_LIBRARY:/usr/lib64/sasl2/; ./cppapplication_1
```

Comment: I have Lots of .so files like this. So how to add?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your updates. But still getting the same response.

Comment: All the below are in /usr/lib64/sasl2/ libanonymous.so.2 => not found
 libcrammd5.so.2 => not found
 libdigestmd5.so.2 => not found
 libgssapiv2.so.2 => not found
 liblogin.so.2 => not found
 libplain.so.2 => not found
 libsasldb.so.2 => not found

Comment: I am sorry I tried your update2 also. Still am getting the same error.

Comment: You might like to check whether the entry `/usr/lib64/sasl2/libanonymous.so.2`isn't just a link to another file, which then in turn is missing. @2vision2

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
ldd <name of executable>
```

You will see dependent libs and their expected paths. See if the lib is present at the path executable is expecting.

Comment: I did I get the below response.linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff53bff000)
 libanonymous.so.2 => not found
 libcrammd5.so.2 => not found
 libdigestmd5.so.2 => not found
 libgssapiv2.so.2 => not found
 liblogin.so.2 => not found
 libplain.so.2 => not found
 libsasldb.so.2 => not found
 libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00000039f6000000)
But libanonymous.so.2 is present in the directory "/usr/lib64/sasl2/libanonymous.so.2"